# Parent classes methods are inherited by reference or by value

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, methods

My question is, if I have a parent class with method called 'speak', and it extends let`s say 3 other child classes and then I instantiate 3 objects from each 3 child classes and so I wind up with 9 object in the memory, then will I have the method called 'speak' (on the parent class) 9 times in the memory and have 'speak'-s definition on each object or will I have just a pointer on each object to the 'speak' method on the parent class and so I will have in the memory the 'speak' method just once (obviously in case if I dont override the 'speak' in the child classes)

```
<?php

class Animal
{
    public $color;

    function __construct($color)
    {
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    public function speak ()
    {
        echo 'I am method 1 from '.$this->color.' animal <br><br>';
    }
}

class RedAnimal extends Animal
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('red');
    }
}

class GreenAnimal extends Animal
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('green');
    }
}

class YellowAnimal extends Animal
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('Yellow');
    }
}

$redAnimal = new RedAnimal();
$greenAnimal = new GreenAnimal();
$yellowAnimal = new YellowAnimal();

$redAnimal->speak();
$greenAnimal->speak();
$yellowAnimal->speak();
```

Comment: An 'object' in memory is just the data needed to keep the state of that object.  The code which provides the functionality of the class is a separate thing altogether.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand, so are you saying that properties will be loaded into the memory and the props will be loaded for each class but they wil reference their methods from one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- An object of class `RedAnimal` will have all methods and properties of inherited class `Animal` that are not private. [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). So in your example there will be only 3 objects of `RedAnimal, GreenAnimal and YellowAnimal` in memory and as you have instantiated 3 objects of each, it will have 9 objects in memory. Each of 9 objects will have there own `speak` method in separate address space in memory.
- However if you declare `speak` method in parent class i.e Animal as `static` it will be loaded in memory only once and stay there till there are any references to it. All other objects of child classes will use the same method which is in memory. This method will be loaded only ONCE being static.
- There are types of memory i.e heap, stack etc. I have not focused on what goes where in memory.

Comment: Kamran do you have an article or any reference about this? thanks